# Reason for inconsistency with Ohm's Law, of current measurements in resistor connected to battery circuit?

Tags: voltage, batteries, resistance, current-measurement, ohms-law

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGIMn2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Connecting various resistors to the same two batteries rated 1.5 V and 9 V as  shown in schematic above returns unexpected results: lower the resistance of R1, lower the current in respect to expected value (as per Ohm's Law).

Would appreciate explanation or hint as to why this happens.

[image: Table 1]

Comment: Search for multi-meter burden voltage such as, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/203598/possibly-incorrect-current-reading/

Comment: Try measuring the voltage across the resistor instead.  And add the *expected* reading to your table.  I'd expect the 9v in particular to sag severely with a 12 ohm load.

Comment: Less than 400 *micro* Ampères at 12 Ohm on 1.5V?! Is that a coin cell battery?

Comment: It was AA / LR6 battery, although the multimeter used appears to have 3K9 Ω [shunt resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org./wiki/Multimeter#Burden_voltage).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your schematic is wrong. The correct one is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe5zja.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The Amperemeter has an internal resistance Ramp of maybe 0.1Ω, to measure a voltage over it (that voltage is then shown as "Ampere" I=Vamp/Ramp), and more important, the battery also has an internal resistance, too. The 9V block in particular is made of six very small 1.5V cells, and their already high internal resistances add up due to the series connection.

The lower the resistance Rtest is, the more these low internal resistances matter.

Comment: The battery's internal source resistance (Rbatt) is not constant either, it varies with temperature and state of charge (how much energy is left). The battery datasheets have some graphs worth studying: [Energizer522 9V Alkaline Battery](https://data.energizer.com/PDFs/522.pdf), [Energizer E91 AA Alkaline Battery](https://data.energizer.com/PDFs/E91.pdf)